# ros2 mppi controller for dynamic obstacles

Tags: ros2, nav2, local-planner

I have been attempting to fine-tune the MPPI controller to avoid dynamic obstacles that are not detected by the global planner. However, I have been unsuccessful. The behavior observed is as follows: the robot approaches the obstacle and slows down upon entering the cost-space, continuously oscillating at a slow pace with some degree of jitter. Despite several attempts to rectify this, including reducing the repulsion_weight as suggested by the documentation, the issue persists.[image]